# Can Hive deal with binary data?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can Hive deal with unstructured data .
If we are having image file in oracle database and we have to run sqoopout to load that image from oracle to another source database and export as well in hive table.
Could you please help me on same how to handled that image file in hive?????

Answer (score 1):

Your Oracle data is probably stored as BLOB.
In Hive it should be stored as [BINARY](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-MiscTypes).

Here is an Hortonworks article demonsrating sqoop import of oracle blob into hive

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/49145/how-to-sqoop-import-oracle-blobclob-data-into-hive.html

Here is an example for processing of binary type using Hive UDF

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFBase64.java